# ShrarePoint moveto operation flags issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint

I am trying to use the SharePoint REST API method `moveto(newurl, flags)` to move a document library to a `Archived` library. However, I am having some issue with the flags.

```
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + path + "')/moveto(newurl='Archived',flags=1)",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
             "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                       "X-RequestDigest" : $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
             },
            success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Moved");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Error");
            }
});
```

`path` is just the path to the document library.

The error response I am getting is

> {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   parameter name flags is not valid."}}}

I am not sure what is wrong with the flags in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that folders don't have a moveto or copyto operation so I will have to copy the contents into a new folder.

Used this :

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105460/spfolder-moveto-functionality-in-javascript